# gcc returning - /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/parser.h:17:7: error: redefinition of 'union YYSTYPE'

Tags: c, perl

Perl Version : 5.26

O/S = RHEL 8.7

I am new to adding Perl into 'C' programs and so am trying to following the examples in [perlembed](https://docs.mojolicious.org/perlembed#Adding-a-Perl-interpreter-to-your-C-program) so I can use it in a project I am working on. However, I am hitting issues e.g.

```
In file included from /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perl.h:3939, from interp.c:2:
/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/parser.h:17:7: error: redefinition of 'union YYSTYPE'
 union YYSTYPE
       ^~~~~~~
```

(see other similar errors in below section)

The environment I am running on is described below:

```
$cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.7 (Ootpa)

$ls -la /bin/cc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 3 Jul 20  2022 /bin/cc -> gcc

$gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/lto-wrapper
..
..
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --disable-libmpx --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-15) (GCC)

$ perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 26 subversion 3) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=linux
..
..
..
`PERL_INCLUDE="/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE"`
  @INC:
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
  
$ perl -MConfig -e 'print $Config{libs}'

returns

-lpthread -lresolv -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc -lgdbm_compat
```

If I try to compile the 'interp.c' program below

```
 #include <EXTERN.h>               /* from the Perl distribution     */
 #include <perl.h>                 /* from the Perl distribution     */

 static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;  /***    The Perl interpreter    ***/

 int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
 {
PERL_SYS_INIT3(&argc,&argv,&env);
        my_perl = perl_alloc();
        perl_construct(my_perl);
PL_exit_flags |= PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;
        perl_parse(my_perl, NULL, argc, argv, (char **)NULL);
        perl_run(my_perl);
        perl_destruct(my_perl);
        perl_free(my_perl);
PERL_SYS_TERM();
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

using either of the following

```
gcc -o interp interp.c `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts`
```

or

```
gcc -O2 -Dbool=char -DHAS_BOOL -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -o interp interp.c -lperl -lm
```

I get the following errors

--- cut here ---

```
In file included from /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perl.h:3939,
                 from interp.c:2:
/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/parser.h:17:7: error: redefinition of 'union YYSTYPE'
 union YYSTYPE
       ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perl.h:3899,
                 from interp.c:2:
/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perly.h:164:7: note: originally defined here
 union YYSTYPE
       ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perl.h:3939,
                 from interp.c:2:
/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/parser.h:28:23: error: conflicting types for 'YYSTYPE'
 typedef union YYSTYPE YYSTYPE;
                       ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perl.h:3899,
                 from interp.c:2:
/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perly.h:175:23: note: previous declaration of 'YYSTYPE' was here
 typedef union YYSTYPE YYSTYPE;
                       ^~~~~~~
```

--- cut here ---

I have grep'ed for YYSTYPE in the header files below but assume I should not have to change the headers supplied with the perl distribution

$grep -i YYSTYPE /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perl.h
no matches

$grep -i YYSTYPE /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/parser.h

```
#ifndef YYSTYPE
union YYSTYPE
typedef union YYSTYPE YYSTYPE;
# define YYSTYPE_IS_TRIVIAL 1
# define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED 1
    YYSTYPE val;    /* semantic value */
    YYSTYPE         yylval;     /* value of lookahead symbol, set by yylex() */
    YYSTYPE     nextval[5];     /* value of next token, if any */
```

$grep -i YYSTYPE /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perly.h

```
#if ! defined YYSTYPE && ! defined YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED
union YYSTYPE
typedef union YYSTYPE YYSTYPE;
# define YYSTYPE_IS_TRIVIAL 1
# define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED 1
```

Can any one help me with the solution to this please, so that the program will compile. If the header files need changing then is there a way to use my own copies of them and change them instead of the ones bundled with RHEL ?

Update 17/01/24

I manually applied the fix @amphetamachine suggested however it still had one of the errors and I tried to apply the same manual fix to parser.h but it did not fix it.

$perl -v  (with manually fixes applied)

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 57 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

```
$gcc -o interp interp.c `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts`
```

In file included from /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perl.h:3939,
from interp.c:2:

> ```
> /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/parser.h:18:7: error: redefinition of 'union YYSTYPE'
>  union YYSTYPE
>    ^~~~~~~ In file included from /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perl.h:3899,
>              from interp.c:2: /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perly.h:167:7: note: originally defined here  union YYSTYPE
>    ^~~~~~~
> ```

I downloaded a later version (v5.38.2) and it seems to fix all the issues and compile the program successfully

$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 38, subversion 2 (v5.38.2) built for x86_64-linux

(Note I have to include the -O option)

$gcc -O -o interp interp.c `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts`

compiled successfully

Thanks for your help @amphetamachine for showing that these were perl version related bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently this is a bug that was fixed in commit [3f5e954](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/3f5e95437092ccddc2436cb7a9ec1cad9e1e8f5d). Authored 2017-11-16, the fix was released as part of Perl v5.27.6.

Either:

- Upgrade to Perl 5.28.0 or later
- Apply the patch manually to your copy of /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/perly.h.

I.e. Move the `typedef union YYSTYPE YYSTYPE;` line **above** the `union YYSTYPE` block.

```
diff --git a/perly.h b/perly.h
index eb14b421c7..7906ab5eb1 100644
--- a/perly.h
+++ b/perly.h
@@ -160,7 +160,7 @@ S_is_opval_token(int type) {
 #endif /* PERL_IN_TOKE_C */
 #endif /* PERL_CORE */
 #if ! defined YYSTYPE && ! defined YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED
-
+typedef union YYSTYPE YYSTYPE;
 union YYSTYPE
 {

@@ -171,8 +171,6 @@ union YYSTYPE
     GV *gvval;

 };
-
-typedef union YYSTYPE YYSTYPE;
 # define YYSTYPE_IS_TRIVIAL 1
 # define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED 1
 #endif
--
2.43.0
```